# Find distinct values, not distinct counts in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, distinct

[Elasticsearch documentation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/cardinality.html)  <del>suggests</del>* that their piece of code

**documentation fixed*

```
GET /cars/transactions/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_colors": {
      "cardinality": {
        "field": "color"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

corresponds to sql query

```
SELECT DISTINCT(color) FROM cars
```

but it actually corresponds to

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(color)) FROM cars
```

I don't want to know how many distinct values I have but what are the distinct values. Anyone knows how to achieve that?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465215/elasticsearch-return-unique-values

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use a [terms aggregation](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on the `color` field. And you need to pay attention to how that field you want to get distinct values on is analyzed, meaning you need to make sure you're not tokenizing it while indexing, otherwise every entry in the aggregation will be a different term that is part of the field content.

If you still want tokenization AND to use the `terms` aggregation you might want to look at `not_analyzed` type of indexing for that field, and maybe use [multi fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-types.html#_multi_fields).

Terms aggregation for cars:

```
GET /cars/transactions/_search?search_type=count
{
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_colors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i add additional fields on response?

Comment: What changes must be made in the query if `color` field were present inside a nested structure as mentioned below  

```|-- constituent_colors: array (nullable = true)  
|    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)  
|    |    |-- color: string (nullable = true)  
|    |    |-- color_code: string (nullable = true) ```

Answer (score 54):

To update the excellent answer from Andrei Stefan, we need to say that the query parameter `search_type=count` is no more supported in Elasticsearch 5. The new way of doing this is to add `"size" : 0` in the body such as :

```
GET /cars/transactions/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_colors": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "color",
        "size": 1000
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What does the 1000 mean?

Comment: In terms aggregation, the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size) says that : `The size parameter can be set to define how many term buckets should be returned out of the overall terms list.`

Comment: Term aggregations by default return 10 buckets only. "size" specifies number of buckets required in response. See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_size

Comment: @NaymeshMistry Exactly. I used `size=1000` only to respect the original OP request but you can remove it and obtain the default `size=10` value.

Comment: If the field, in this case `color` is analysed, you need to reference the `keyword` field. ES will show an "illegal_argument_exception" error with the message "Fielddata is disabled on text fields by default..." In that case, instead of `"field": "color",`, it should say `"field": "color.keyword",`

Comment: I want to get full document or few fields for that distinct record. Anyone tried this?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, both of the answers were arcane to me and hopelessly complex when I wanted to add multiple filters.

For me, what made sense was to go on the Discover tab and apply the filters I wanted. I then saved my search.

Then, I created a new Bar Chart visualization using my saved search. I then modified the X-Axis to use Terms aggregation based on my field of interest (in my case, Usernames), and then order by Count. Make sure the Size is something large, like 500.

You should be able to get the results in tabular form underneath your chart. Simple, and no complex JSON programming. Just a series of clicks. You can even save the visualization for later.

Answer (score 3):

While I appreciate the idea of leveraging Kibana to answer this question, I was unable to accomplish it in exactly the way [described by @Phlucious](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52656323/5025060).  Here is how I proceeded (Kibana and Elasticsearch 7.8.1):

1. Open Kibana's ***main*** Discover tool: [image: main Kibana Discover menu location] and click its *Add filter* link to narrow your search as much as possible;
2. In Kibana's *Available fields* side-menu, left-click on the field you wish to extract distinct values of (in my case, *data.vulnerability.package.condition*):[image: Kibana Available fields menu]
3. This will open a menu containing the top 5 values of this field, followed by a button labelled *Visualize*.  Click on *Visualize* to open a visualization of the top values of your field:[image: visualization]
4. Left-click the *Inspect* link above this chart. A sub-screen opens in which you may view the top values for your selected field:[image: sub-screen]
5. In the upper right-hand corner of this sub-screen find a link labelled *View: Data*.  Left-click it to choose *Requests* instead.  In the header of the new sub-screen which appears you may click *Request* to access the Elasticsearch query Kibana used to generate your graph and chart:[image: requests]

Note that the value for *size* in my Request as shown in the image above is 100; initially it was 20, which is Kibana's default setting for *Number of terms*.  I changed it to 100 in Kibana's *Advanced Settings* screen:[image: Number of terms setting]

Comment: There is no visualise button in Version: 6.5.4, can you tell me how to do the same in this version?