# To find the distinct fields in an elastic search query

Tags: elasticsearch, field

I need the values of only one field and there are duplicate values in it.

```
POST _search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
               {"term": {
           "report": {
              "value": "some_value"
           }
        }}
            ]
        }
    },
    "fields": [
            "field_name"
    ]
}
```

I need only the distinct values of field_name.

Answer (score 0):

What if you have your query, with the use of `terms` aggregation and then by applying a [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) aggregation in order to narrow down to the single value which you wanted to achieve:

```
"aggs": {
    "values": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "your_field"
      }
    }
  }
```

This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189725/find-distinct-values-not-distinct-counts-in-elasticsearch) could be helpful as well.