# Elasticsearch - Distinct Values, Not Counts

Tags: php, elasticsearch, foselasticabundle

I am trying to do something similar to this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE fileContent LIKE '%keyword%' AND company_id = '1' GROUP BY email
```

Having read posts [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189725/find-distinct-values-not-distinct-counts-in-elasticsearch) I have this:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [{
                "match": {
                    "fileContent": {
                        "query": "keyword"
                    }
                }
            }],
            "filter": [{
                "terms": {
                    "company_id": [1]
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "group_by_email": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "email",
                "size": 1000
            }
        }
    },
    "size": 0
}
```

Field mappings are:

```
{
  "cvs" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "application" : {
        "_meta" : {
          "model" : "Acme\\AppBundle\\Entity\\Application"
        },
        "dynamic_date_formats" : [ ],
        "properties" : {
          "email" : {
            "type" : "keyword"
          },
          "fileContent" : {
            "type" : "text"
          },
          "company_id" : {
            "type" : "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

... which are generated from Symfony config.yml:

```
fos_elastica:
    clients:
        default:
            host: "%elastica.host%"
            port: "%elastica.port%"
    indexes:
        cvs:
            client: default
            types:
               application:
                    properties:
                        fileContent: ~
                        email:
                          index: not_analyzed
                        company_id: ~
                    persistence:
                        driver: orm
                        model: Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Application
                        provider: ~
                        finder: ~
```

The filter works fine, but I am finding that `hits:hits` returns no items (or all results matching the search if I remove `size:0`) and `aggregations:group_by_email:buckets` has a count of the groups but not the records themselves. The records that were grouped aren't returned and it's these that I need.

I have also tried with FOSElasticBundle using the query builder if this is your preferred flavour (this works but doesn't have the grouping/aggregation):

```
$boolQuery = new \Elastica\Query\BoolQuery();

$filterKeywords = new \Elastica\Query\Match();
$filterKeywords->setFieldQuery('fileContent', 'keyword');
$boolQuery->addMust($filterKeywords);

$filterUser = new \Elastica\Query\Terms();
$filterUser->setTerms('company_id', array('1'));
$boolQuery->addFilter($filterUser);

$finder = $this->get('fos_elastica.finder.cvs.application');
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`top_hits:{size:1}` appears to be what I need, having played around with Andrei's answer. This will return one record for each bucket in the aggregation

```
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_email": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "email",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sample_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Ref: [top_hits](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html)

Answer (score 1):

For this you need [`top_hits` aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.4/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html) inside the `terms` one you are already using:

```
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_email": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "email",
        "size": 1000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "sample_docs": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 100
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. ``buckets`` now contains ``hits:hits`` with the results, but it's still all records that match the search/filter. Looking at ``hits:hits:0:_source:email`` and ``hits:hits:1:source:email`` I see the same email address as if it's not been grouped (the email is split with the ``@`` into two buckets, but that's something I can resolve with index types I believe)?

Comment: What's the mapping of your `email` field?

Comment: Added to the question to make it easier to read, hope it's what you're after?

Comment: Your `email` field is  of type `keyword` which means it will not be split. Since you see the split on `@` it means something is wrong with your mapping. Check the `_mapping` of your index from Elasticsearch itself (`GET /your_index_name/_mapping`) and see what kind of field `email` is. I know you provided the mapping, but according to that mapping ES shouldn't split on `@`. Maybe you are not looking at the correct mapping or at the correct index...

Comment: I added the `index: not_analyzed` to the mapping which prevents the splitting on the `@`. I changed `top_hits: {size: 1}` which only returns one result per bucket, this gets the results I want (I'll post an answer later to reflect this). Paginating `top_hits` is another issue for another day. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

`top_hits` helped me too. I had some trouble too, but eventually figured out how to resolve it. **So here is my solution:**

```
{
    "query": {
        "nested": {
            "path": "placedOrders",
            "query": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "placedOrders.ownerId": "0a9fdef0-4508-4f9c-aa8c-b3984e39ad1e"
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "custom_name1": {
            "nested": {
                "path": "placedOrders"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "custom_name2": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "placedOrders.propertyId"
                    },
                    "aggs": {
                        "custom_name3": {
                            "top_hits": {
                                "size": 1,
                                "sort": [
                                    {
                                        "placedOrders.propertyId": {
                                            "order": "desc"
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```