# Distinct Values for one field with corresponding fields in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, distinct

I want the corresponding query in Elastic for

`SELECT DISTINCT(color),car_price FROM cars;`.

I have gone through below given [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189725/find-distinct-values-not-distinct-counts-in-elasticsearch) . which is having only field in buckets as key but I need corresponding fields with key in buckets.

Comment: You can use `terms` to get distinct colors and nested `top_hits` to other fields.

Comment: @khachik can you put up query , as I am new to Elasticsearch.

Comment: @khachik , Thanks got needed result.