# Elasticsearch - How to return distinct documents for certain fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the next elasticsearch query and I need to know how to get only distinct results for certain fields. (Like an sql distinct: SELECT DISTINCT column1 , column2, ...
FROM table_name :wink:

Here is my query

```
{
  "_source": ["part", "manufacturer", "shortdesc"],
  "query": {
  "match": {
       "part": "2n2222"
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the results that i'm getting:

```
{
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "13921",
    "_score" : 207.16005,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "13923",
    "_score" : 207.16005,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "811202",
    "_score" : 202.03964,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "534059",
    "_score" : 202.03964,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "534062",
    "_score" : 202.03964,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "144303",
    "_score" : 202.03964,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "557240",
    "_score" : 202.03964,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Infineon"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "13924",
    "_score" : 201.24086,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "557235",
    "_score" : 201.24086,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "55566",
    "_score" : 201.24086,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "50873",
    "_score" : 201.24086,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "13915",
    "_score" : 199.76857,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "591924",
    "_score" : 199.76857,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "526043",
    "_score" : 199.76857,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "423282",
    "_score" : 198.89282,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "565951",
    "_score" : 193.51782,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "P2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "ON Semiconductor"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "13920",
    "_score" : 192.1505,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "P2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "ON Semiconductor"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "2885944",
    "_score" : 191.28773,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "Q2N2222A",
      "manufacturer" : "Freescale Semiconductor"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "765656",
    "_score" : 191.28773,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222AL",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi"
    }
  },
  {
    "_index" : "my_index",
    "_type" : "_doc",
    "_id" : "491090",
    "_score" : 190.78474,
    "_source" : {
      "part" : "2N2222AUB",
      "manufacturer" : "Microsemi Corporation"
    }
  }
```

A record is considered duplicated if it contains the same part and manufacturer. I need to get distinct values for those fields.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to use an aggregation in you query to get that distinct pair behavior. see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28189725/find-distinct-values-not-distinct-counts-in-elasticsearch) for an example of distinct value query.

The main difference between linked question and your case is that you have two fields, and you need all distinct pairs, not distinct values of both fields.

EDIT:
Just tested this and it seems to have a behavior like what you're trying to do. You could probably optimize it by removing/disabling the count of doc_count of the terms aggregations and using the _source like you do in you question. You can also add you query and match clauses to filter to a given part/manufacturer.

EDIT2: added the query/match to the request as in the question.

```
GET YOURINDEX/_search
{
"query": {
    "match": {
      "part.keyword": "2n2222"
    }
  }, 
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "actions": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "part.keyword"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "emails": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "manufacturer.keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much friend

Comment: Thank you so much friend, But it doesn't working yet. I updated my question

Comment: what is the result you are expecting?

The previous query returns you a list of manufacturer for each parts. so you can basically parse it and from the response format, get a part->manufacturer pair for each distincs pairs in your data (and just ignore the count and other stuff in the response)

Do you want an actual document to be returned for each distinct pair of values, return a single document for a given pair of values, even if there are several with the same? In which case i would recommend to look into the top hits aggregation.

Comment: I want to return different results for part and manufacturer. A record is considerated duplicated if has the same part and manufacturer