# How to get distinct results in ElasticSearch if a field is the same

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an ElasticSearch service version 1.4 with an index 40M record of data.

I have data that has the same parent field. I would like to extract 1 unique result out of the same parent only.

Ex:

```
{
    "id": "7835",
    "isbn": "3985",
    "parent_id": "7819",
},
{
    "id": "1835",
    "isbn": "4935",
    "parent_id": "7719",
},
{
    "id": "2835",
    "isbn": "9985",
    "parent_id": "7819",
}
```

The expected result that I would like to have is:

```
{
    "id": "7835",
    "isbn": "3985",
    "parent_id": "7819",
},
{
    "id": "1835",
    "isbn": "4935",
    "parent_id": "7719",
},
```

I have checked out aggregations:
[ElasticSearch - Return Unique Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465215/elasticsearch-return-unique-values)

```
{
    "aggs" : {
    "parentId" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "parent_id" }
}
```

However the response I get - show the 3 items (so the last one doesn't get ignored), and I have term buckets with the key afterwards inside the aggregations response, which to me is not useful as it seems to tell me how many occurrence per key inside the doc, which is not the desired output.

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand, but have you tried nesting another `terms` sub-aggregation on the `isbn` (or `id`) field inside the one for `parent_id`?

Comment: @Val Sorry about that - you are correct - I have changed the output to reflect the correct result

Answer (score 0):

In order not to search for original document, you should add `"size":0` above aggregation.

You can see only the number of documents per each `parent_id` in `buckets` field of response.

```
{
    "size" : 0,
    "aggs" : {
    "parentId" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "parent_id" }
    }
}
```

Comment: no, match won't work because match means you want a specific result of parent_id - I need to make  sure that the parent_id result being returned is unique and discard all those who are repeated.

Comment: but in your `expected result`, there are two records with same parent_id.

Comment: Sorry about that - you are correct - I have changed the output to reflect the correct result