# elasticsearch - comprehensive list of distinct values

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to find all distinct values of a term over a time range.

Example data:

```
[
  {
    'a': 123,
    'b': 456,
    'user': 'bob',
  },
  {
    ...
    'user': 'sally',
    ...
  },
  {
    ...
    'user': 'bob',
    ...
  },
  {
    'x': 2,
    'y': 3,
  }
]
```

In this case I want to find all distinct values of `user`.

Note that some `user`s will appear in multiple records, and not all records have a `user`.

Also, my requirement is that the list of returned `user`s MUST be comprehensive (ie. if there exists a record with a certain `user`, then that `user` MUST appear in the list of results).

Having the number of occurrences of each `user` would be nice too, but not required.

I considered [Cardinality Aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) but I'm concerned about the 'approximate' nature of the results. I need a comprehensive list of `user`s.

How can I do this in elasticsearch?

Comment: Have you tried a [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch - Return Unique Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465215/elasticsearch-return-unique-values)

Comment: @SloanAhrens I see that [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) also says it has approximate counts. Is it guaranteed that terms that appear 0 times will not be in the results, and terms that appear >= 1 times will be in the results?

Comment: @mark Yes, as long as you set the size parameter to be zero, which is really setting it to Integer.MAX_VALUE (usually 2,147,483,647) and you don't have more than Integer.MAX_VALUE unique users in your index.  Read the size section of the documentation you linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments [terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.1/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) is the one you are looking for. Results are approximate only if you query `N` most common terms and data is split in multiple shards.

You can set `size` to zero to get "unlimited" (`Integer.MAX_VALUE`) results.