# Get distinct values from a field in ElasticSearch via a REST API URI

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following URI which should retrieve all values from the Gender field.

```
http://localhost:9200/persons/_search?_source=Gender
```

However, it does not return me all the data in the index of the Gender field. I want to get the data distinct also.

I am consuming this REST API in AngularJS. Can someone help me to achieve this type of URI query ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Elasticsearch returns [10 hits by default](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html#search-request-from-size), unless otherwise specified by `size`.

To get distinct values of a field use `terms aggregation`.

Refer: [ES-return-unique-values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465215/elasticsearch-return-unique-values)