# How to perform a distinct count query in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with a host field. I am trying to retrieve the count of documents by distinct host name.

IE:

```
Host1: 
    Count: 72
Host2:
    Count: 33
Host3:
    Count: 153
```

Each document has a host field and it is a string. I assume I need to do something involving terms and cardinality, but I can't quite nail the syntax.

Comment: You need to use the Terms Aggregation.  Possible Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25465215/elasticsearch-return-unique-values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ## **How to get all possible values for field `host`?**

```
curl -XGET  http://localhost:9200/articles/_search?pretty -d '
{
    "aggs" : {
        "whatever_you_like_here" : {
            "terms" : { "field" : "host", "size":10000 }
        }
    },
    "size" : 0
}'
```

Note

- The result will contain a `doc_count` for each unique value
- `"size":10000` Get at most 10000 unique values. Default is 10.
- `"size":0` By default, `"hits"` contains 10 documents. We don't need them.
- By default, the buckets are ordered by the `doc_count` in decreasing order.

---

Reference: [bucket terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html)